# vba-style compiler/gui for python

Tags: python, vba, compiler-construction

does anyone know if there a vba style compiler/gui for python. i am using the regular IDLE and it is difficult to navigate from function to function. with the VBA editor you are able to skip from function to function with a listbox. does anyone know if such a thing exists for python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn a decent text editor, and learn it well.

In vim for instance, I would search for **def func** and get there WAY faster than you ever could using your mouse in a drop-down list.

Comment: vim FTW. Plenty of vimscripts available to tweak vim for Python use, plus you can extend vim with Python now (if you have the right version).

Answer (score 6):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) can do this.  [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) apparently can too.

Answer (score 2):

there are several Frameworks for GUI programming and some GUI-Editors/IDEs

a summery on what frameworks exists, is available in [the python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)

Which to use depends largely on your preferences, the plattform you are using and your skills

Answer (score 0):

[PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/"This is the download page.") is good and is actively developed.